# Как сделать выборку только из одной таблицы?

Tags: java, hibernate

Есть 4 таблицы в базе и все они связаны между собой,нужно вывести данные только из одной таблицы.Использую `hibernate`, и когда вывожу данные из одной таблицы выходят записи и из других таблиц.Получается вечная рекурсия,но меня не это напрягает а то что : допустим есть таблица курьеры и заказы.У одного курьера может быть много заказов , а у заказа есть поле которое смотрит на курьера.Заказов будет много а курьер только один.Вот тут проблема когда я вывожу один заказ в нем один курьер а внутри курьера все его заказы которые мне не нужны.Как это решается без? У меня каскадные связи,помогите пожалуйста.

метод получения :

```
public List<Order> getOrders(int shopId){
        Criteria criteria = session.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Order.class);
        criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("shops.id",shopId));
        List<Order> orders  = criteria.list();
        return orders;
    }
```

Order.class

```
@Entity(name = "Order")
@Table(name = "order")
public class Order{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "order_id")
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "courier_id")
    private Courier courier;//хочу избавиться от этого курьера.



    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "shops_id")
    private Shops shops;
```

Comment: `fetch = FetchType.LAZY`

Comment: @not a Programmer и на курьера?

Comment: ааа.так вот для чего она...спасибо.

Comment: Да, да, она именно для этого